# Angular 2 - How to get possible siblings of activated route?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I am trying to build a service which takes the ActivatedRoute and goes through all configurations of it's sibling routes, too.

I know how to access the children of an ActivatedRoute, but how to get those childrens siblings?

For example:

Routing:

```
[{
 path: 'path1',
 component: Path1Component,
 children: [{
       path: 'path2',
       component: Path2Component,
       data: {somekey: 'somedata'}
    },
    {
       path: 'path3',
       component: Path3Component,
       data: {somekey: 'someotherdata'}
    }]
}]
```

If my ActivatedRoute would contain (or point to) path3, how to get the data contained in path 2?

Is there a way?

Answer (score 1):

you can get it using `router.config`,

so in your component where you want to check data for other routes,

```
constructor(private router: Router){
     console.log(router.config);
}
```

you will have to dig path in the object and get data.

Now do note that this configuration changes as and when lazy loaded module gets loaded and **you won't be able to get data for lazy loaded routes until they are loaded**.

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to do it, you can access the route's parent and then the parent's children, which will also contain your current route. Like this:

```
this.route.parent.children
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how you do it:

`this.route.parent.routeConfig.children`